# How can a release pipeline access a build pipepline's working folder?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Many of our build pipelines include a "command line" task that is used to create a "setup.exe" from the contents of the build output folder ("\agent_work\nn\**s**\..."). The location of this folder is accessed via the build variable `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)`.

I've never utilised *release* pipelines before today, partly because I've never understood their purpose, but have decided to have a play with this feature. I've now created a release pipeline and moved the above command line task from the build pipeline and into the release pipeline's stage. Unsurprisingly the command fails because the above build variable is pointing to a completely different working folder ("\agent\_work\nn\**r1**\a\..."), which is empty.

I'm possibly being a bit naive here and not understanding how or what release pipelines are used for, but is it possible for the release pipeline to know what the working directory is of the triggering build pipeline?

**Edit**: After some more reading it appears that the release pipeline is supposed to download the "artifact" from the triggering build pipeline, I've noticed these in the log, which looks suspicious:

```
Preparing to get the list of available artifacts from build
Preparing to download artifact: build.SourceLabel
##[warning]Release management does not support download of artifact type TfvcLabel in the current version
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, you could look into this document [Release Artifacts and Artifacts sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops) for more reference.

And I suppose that you could check the option to skip the warning message.
[image]

======================================================

Update 1

You usually used the Build Pipeline to build / create your software binaries (e. g. dotnet publish or ng build --prod) and stored these artifacts in the Azure DevOps drop location.

When you had a Release Pipeline that gets triggered with these build artifacts (software binaries) and deploys them to one or many stages.

The reason to separate these two pipelines (build and release) is that you want to build a specific version of your software only once and then use the same binaries in each of your target environment (e. g. dev / test / production).

With the release pipeline, you usually use the first Stage to build your artifacts, and the next Stages to deploy it - similar as before but in one module.

And you could check the document [Classic Release Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) for more references.

Comment: That option is unchecked. I suspect the real problem is I don't understand the relationship between a build pipeline and a release pipeline. Should I be doing something in the build pipeline (which is building a .Net solution) to make that build output accessible to the release pipeline?

Comment: @AndrewStephens , Hi andrew, you could check my update for more reference

Comment: I think this comes down to my lack of understanding of releases. After some investigation it seems that I have to add a couple of new tasks to my build pipeline: one to copy the build output to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, followed by a "publish artifact" task. Only then can the release pipeline access the files. All this seems unnecessarily complicated, resulting in duplication of files and folders in numerous places, so I think I'll go back to doing everything I need in the build pipeline.

Comment: @AndrewStephens, hi andrew, did my post help with your issue? what could I help more on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Although I've accepted Ceeno's answer, I thought I would elaborate on what I did, as I've personally found many concepts of Azure DevOps releases to be very unclear. Possibly a case of too much documentation and unable to see the wood for the trees.

My existing build pipeline builds a WPF desktop app, with the build output ending up in a folder similar to:

```
\[agent]\_work\35\s\...\x64\release\
```

In order to get my new release pipeline working I had to add a "Copy files" task - in the *build* pipeline - that copies the contents of the above build output folder to an "artifact staging directory" - a target field of `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. With my build the physical location of this staging directory is

```
\[agent]\_work\35\a\
```

I then had to add a "Publish artifact" task, again in the *build* pipeline, to publish the contents of this artifact staging directory. I've no idea what the physical published location of this is, as the build log only says that it was published to a "file container".

Having done this, my *release* pipeline was then able to access the contents of this published artifact, allowing me to run a powershell task to generate a setup.exe using Innosetup. Interestingly the release pipeline copies the contents of the published artifact to a working folder of its own, in my case:

```
[agent]\_work\r1\a\...
```

So all those files have been duplicated in at least three different locations. It all seems unnecessarily complicated unless I'm missing something to all this!